# Problem with SelectedValue when Sorted is true (ComboBox)

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, combobox

When setting `ComboBox.Sorted` to `true`, `ComboBox.SelectedValue` returns a different values than the visibly selected value.

Load items and show:

```cs
using (ModelContext model = new ModelContext())
{
    cbWorker.ValueMember = "IdWorker";
    cbWorker.DisplayMember = "FullName";

    bindingWorker.DataSource = model.Workers.Select(x => new ItemWorker{
            IdWorker = x.Id,
            FullName = x.FullName
        })
        .ToList();

    cbWorker.DataSource = bindingWorker;
}

private void CbWorker_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object x = cbWorker.SelectedValue;
    if (x!= null) label.Text = x.ToString();
}
```

If `ComboBox.Sorted = false`, `SelectedValue` is OK:

[image]

But if `ComboBox.Sorted = true`, `SelectedValue` isn't OK:

[image]

it is possible to fix it? Similar problem with, for example, `CheckedListBox`.

Comment: I will guess that the problem is that the items seem out of order?  Or is it that it appears that a form if the IDWorker is used as the DisplayMember?

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp `"- id: 7"` is `DisplayMember` and `7` is `ValueMember`. When `Sorted = true` - `ValueMember` not correspond `DisplayMember`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `ComboBox.Sorted` to `false` and sort the `bindingWorker.DataSource` by the `IdWorker` property:

```cs
cbWorker.Sorted = false;

...

bindingWorker.DataSource = model.Workers.Select(x => new ItemWorker{
            IdWorker = x.Id,
            FullName = x.FullName
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.IdWorker)
        .ToList();

cbWorker.DataSource = bindingWorker;

cbWorker.ValueMember = "IdWorker";
cbWorker.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

## Explanation:

There are two problems in your example:

1. **Setting ComboBox.Sorted to true on a data-bound ComboBox**
2. **Numeric sorting of ComboBox items using ComboBox.Sorted**

### Setting ComboBox.Sorted to true on a data-bound ComboBox

From [ComboBox.Sorted Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted?view=netframework-4.8) documentation:

> Attempting to set the Sorted property on a data-bound control raises
>   an ArgumentException. You must sort the data using the underlying data
>   model.

It is probably not a good idea to set `ComboBox.Sorted` to `true` on a data-bound `ComboBox`. Even if it is not throwing an exception, it may cause unexpected behavior.

### Numeric sorting of ComboBox items using ComboBox.Sorted

A simple test can show that if `ComboBox.Sorted = true`:

- The items are sorted by the `ComboBox.DisplayMember`
- The items are sorted as strings (something like `item.ToString()`)

This means that even if `ComboBox.DisplayMember` was a numeric type, it would be sorted after calling `ToString()` on each number, so the items would be sorted **alphabetically**, not as numbers.

For example, if the numbers `10, 1, 3` would be sorted directly as numeric values, they would be sorted to `1, 3, 10`, but if the numbers would be first converted to strings (`"10", "1", "3"`) and than sorted, they would be sorted **alphabetically** to `"1", "10", "3"`

## Conclusion

If you want to:

- Sort a data bound `ComboBox`
- Sort `ComboBox` items not **alphabetically**
- Sort by a member other than the `DisplayMember`

You have to sort the items before setting the items as the `ComboBox.DataSource` and set `ComboBox.Sorted` to `false`

Comment: I do not understand why ValueMember is not assigned to its DisplayMember. Both can be strings. Both can be numbers.

Comment: `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` are tow different field of `ComboBox`, I`m not sure I understand your question

Comment: in my understanding, ValueMember is something that should be returned when its DisplayMember is selected. So why when sorting is mixed DisplayMember, but does not change ValueMember (remains in the same sequence).

Comment: this is how to do the sort in Excel on one column. Now you have Anna lives in London, and after sorting lives in Canada.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the cause of the  mismatch between `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` in your example, it may have to do with "Attempting to set the Sorted property on a data-bound control" which is not advised by the documentation. Sorting the data source directly and setting `Sorted` to false is the recommended way and fixes the problem.

Comment: What if I wanna sort by name? say: 1, 10, 2, 3, ... and when I select 10 I get the Id 10 instead of 2 (this would happen because 10 is in the second position).